# How To Use .NET Class Library For Outlook Web Add-In

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Recently, I have created one add-in for Outlook web.
I have to use one class library.
How can I use that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office web add-ins are built based on web technologies such as JavaScript and HTML. They were not designed for .net libraries from the ground. However, with [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) on top of [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) you can call your .net code.

You may find the [Blazor Webassembly Outlook add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/blazor-add-in/outlook-blazor-add-in) sample add-in helpful.